# DateTime Expression Returning Empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I have a custom MVC extension, which accepts an expression of `Expression<Func<TModel, object>>`.  I'm trying to pass in the following list-based expression:

```
i => i.List[i].CreatedDate
```

The expression is correct, and when the expression is a string for a different helper, it works fine.  But when I use it and the value is a date, it's not returning anything when I use it with:

```
Html.IdFor(expression);
```

Even when I use

```
ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
```

it returns empty.  The expression is not null and shows that it maps to the field correctly.  Why, and how do I get expressions to work with dates?

EDIT: The underlying code that runs in the helper is (note:options simply contains the values with get/set properties; it does contain a valid value as the expression).

```
var id = Html.IdFor(options.Expression).ToHtmlString();
var name = Html.NameFor(options.Expression).ToHtmlString();

var tag = new TagBuilder("input");
tag.Attributes.Add("id", id);
tag.Attributes.Add("name", name);

if (options.HtmlAttributes != null)
{
    foreach (var htmlAttribute in options.HtmlAttributes)
    {
        if (htmlAttribute.Value != null)
            tag.Attributes.Add(htmlAttribute.Key, htmlAttribute.Value.ToString());
    }
}

return new MvcHtmlString(tag.ToString());
```

Comment: can you put the code of the extension

Comment: OK, but the extension is very simple, so I don't really see how that's going to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with this definition of Expression:

```
Expression<Func<TModel, object>>
```

You can't use object type; the underlying type has to match exactly the property defined.  Once I made that correction, it works.  I think nullable to non-nullable property (ie. Expr to a DateTime property) is OK, but not object to DateTime.

Comment: When you return an `object` in `Expression<Func<TModel, object>>` and the actual value is of `struct` or `enum` type, the expression tree will contain a *boxing conversion* as the outermost expression in the tree. I don't know MVC, but maybe the [`IdFor` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833709.aspx) handles expression trees with a boxing conversion incorrectly. Wrapping a value type to a `Nullable<>` type is a different conversion than boxing a value type to `object` or to an interface type.